# Natural logarithm problem

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I'm kind of confused on how to solve this problem! Any guidance/advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

$e^{−9}e^{−2}e^{9}$

Comment: Is this what are you trying to write $e^{−9e^{−2e9}}$?

Comment: No, sorry... Newbie. It's supposed to be e^-9 x e^-2 x e^9

Comment: $e^{-9} x e^{-2} x e^{9}$  ? i still don get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general

\begin{align*}
a^b a^c = a^{b+c}
\end{align*}

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{-9}\mathrm{e}^{-2} \mathrm{e}^{9} & = (\mathrm{e}^{-9}\mathrm{e}^{-2}) \mathrm{e}^{9} \\
& = \mathrm{e}^{-11} \mathrm{e}^{9} \\
& = \mathrm{e}^{-2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful. Would you mind telling me/linking me to a page that explains how to do arithmetic with natural logarithms?

Comment: You can find all information about exponents, logarithms and anything related to it on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{−9}e^{−2}e^9=e^{(-9)+(-2)+9}=e^{-9-2+9}=e^{-2}$$

Note that this only works when the exponents have the same base, as is the case here.